# Decimal Digit Truncating

Tags: code-golf, number, floating-point

### Input:

A decimal

### Output:

The input truncated

**How to truncate them?**

The integer part of the input will remain the same. The decimal part of the input will be truncated based on the lowest digit in consecutive order. The two step-by-step examples below should clarify what I mean by that:

*Example 1:* Input: `17.46940822`

Step 1: Leave the integer part unchanged: `17`
Step 2: Look at the first decimal digit, and truncate it to that many decimal digits: `4` → `.4694`
Step 3: Look at the next decimal digit. If it's lower, adjust the truncation accordingly. If not, continue to the next decimal digit: `6` → remains `.4694`
Step 3 again: `9` → remains `.4694`
Step 3 again: `4` → remains `.4694`

So the output will be: `17.4694`.

*Example 2:* Input: `10.4521084`

Step 1: Leave the integer part unchanged: `10`
Step 2: Look at the first decimal digit, and truncate it to that many decimal digits: `4` → `.4521`
Step 3: Look at the next decimal digit. If it's lower, adjust the truncation accordingly. If not, continue to the next decimal digit: `5` → remains `.4521`
Step 3 again: `2` → truncation adjusted to: `.45`

So the output will be: `10.45`

### Challenge rules:

- You are allowed to take the input as decimal, string, list/array/stream of characters, etc. (Same applies to the output, although I doubt there are a lot of languages that have the proper truncation while remain working with decimal values.)
  You are also allowed to use a comma `,` instead of a dot `.` (perhaps useful for regex-based solution/languages).
- If the decimal part is not long enough for the truncation, you are optionally allowed to add trailing zeros. I.e. `123.4` can be both `123.4` or `123.4000`
- If you have to truncate to `0` decimal digits we omit the decimal digits. The dot/comma may remain optionally if you use strings. I.e. `847.3072` → `847` (or `847.`)
- You can assume the input will always contain at least one decimal digit, so `123` won't be an input, but `123.0` can be an input.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Input:          Output:

17.46940822     17.4694
10.4521084      10.45
123.4           123.4000 (or 123.4)
-847.3072       -847 (or -847.)
123.0           123 (or 123.)
98.76543210     98.7654
0.3165          0.3
-0.1365         -0.1
82937.82937     82937.82
-0.1010101      -0.1
-1.0101010      -1 (or -1.)
28.684297       28.68
13.35           13.350 (or 13.35)
0.99999999999   0.999999999
28.321          28.32
0.56462         0.5646
```

Comment: Need we output string?

Comment: @l4m2 No, you are also allowed to output it as a decimal, or list of characters. Although I don't know a lot of languages that can do the proper truncation without converting to string format.

Comment: So it's fine to remove ending zero if outputing float?

Comment: @l4m2 Sure. I've updated the rules to also allow no additional trailing zeros.

Comment: Suggest test case `0.99999999999 -> 0.999999999`

Comment: Suggested test case `0.56462` ([This Jelly code](https://tio.run/##ZZA9TsQwEIX7nMJSChPBDuN/W1BwAGokhCgpWK2EREcHNNyADgpKxAHYerlI9iJhxo6TXbAlK/nezPM8L29Wq4dhuN0@vsHhxfb56@T85/X0ePPef3/0689@/XQ2bF6IXw7DVSNVAOuTxai1PBK0WjEi0hCs0wqjLRJrjEjRBiqsCiNEFAd39@Wna@Qi2gAGg661rWCUa7LWFS/85zXZUEWKELyzhkapM46okQhGebfT3gpCdDOCMrsC3UyokVEnEyCf1ayi0oV5T4lL10JB4TgLqsRQPKKO4KPVKcxBM6J4Boz7E4/R@FD82XGMNC@u5hgTyP4Ufy9mRtzpvPVa7j0Ao@b6Fw) passes all other given test cases :()

Comment: @JonathanAllan Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

2 bytes extra due to a bug with `£` not handling **0** correctly.

```
'.¡`DvÐgsNè-F¨]'.ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXe/QwgSXssMT0ov9Dq/QdTu0IlZd7/De//91LUzM9YwNzI0A)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##JYqxCsJAEET7/QpJk8Zb9nb3cneNlVjaCZYqiFhZBAIB8w9@gI1dfkICuQ87w8nAzJthHu35cr/mZ9f3h1zj/Dltu/S6tfs0mt08DkON6UvpnY9VmlZms0pTtc7WozZRKTCDJVTHloKCZUEFE9SjkOfSCWJA3ziV5QOEYhsHhtDKkoGjeCxeNioCY/FPBBywCcrRgxUU9wM)

**Explanation**

```
    '.¡                 # split input on "."
       `                # push int and decimals separately to stack
        D               # duplicate decimal digits
         v              # for each
          Ð             # triplicate the current decimal digits
           g            # get the length
            sNè         # get the Nth digit
               -        # subtract from the total length
                F¨]     # drop that many digits from the end
                        # end loop
                   '.ý  # join on "."
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>103 101 98</s> <s>94</s> <s>93</s> 87 bytes

```python
a,b=input().split('.');i,w=0,len(b)
while w>i:w=min(int(b[i]),w);i+=1
print a+'.'+b[:w]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1NboMwEIX3PgViM1DIaPyH7VR003bdA0RZhAoplqiDUiq3p6cG0nQsjfzmzZtv/JnOlyDm57eX1zbP8/lUd60P49dUlPg5Dn4qAKF89HVsqR76UHQli2c/9Fl88vvYfvhQ@DAV3cEfyzqmzarlbLymWXaqUrbqDvt4nNNt1n/379lCeuB6Bm5QNU6RFQIYcEKlBSerIEtKSEyftRjsrDIoyQjIbh7dPWfRNFrJFE1XCCVvNPzlCLm8SQZWOGlw7bB5tL6Ft@O4CVqUsNhYJZzZeBKlvvMI3X/BupvY8As)

---

Saved:

- -2 bytes, thanks to Kevin Cruijssen
- -3 bytes, thanks to Vedant Kandoi
- -4 bytes, thanks to Lynn

Comment: `a+w+1` can be `a-~w`. Nice answer though, +1 from me.

Comment: Oh, and `return` can be `print` as well. And here you are golfing Python for years. Tsk tsk tsk. ;p (It's the simplest things we usually forgot to golf I guess.)

Comment: Instead of a function, use n=input() and remove the spaces and print as mentioned by @KevinCruijssen to save a few bytes.

Comment: I think `while w>=i<a+i<len(n):` is okay, as the `.` is never at the start of the string, so `a>0`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks :)
Ye have little faith :( .   I didn't really have time to golf it, I just submitted a working solution, and left for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 58 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,p=1/0,q=1,c=s[q])=>c?f(s.slice(0,p-~c),++c?p:q,q+1):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNbsIwEIX3PoV3eJRksJ1/qtBVT0GRiJxAg0IcMK266tWp7aRAHcny997M5NnH@qs26tKN12jQTXu77StmwrESSx6eKxGqymzOW6jW6nXPDJq@Uy3j4Rj9KAiDQL2Oq3N4DgSszO1lR0SOSVYmvJCSujUzERyTVApeJHTSHRMhY5yFSXXMOadMXyYAEhVJjjHP5Vzj2PveAD@D/59xbwdSFphnaRLbX3t3ZsIxFln66LJMIo4ifhIdk0KWcY5@9@If@2ruv6fqSOCkzYkiMUUVNoosMCsSWebzeM9ExBinz/Edzw/gjmCjlo/lo97JzbRXe3R7th1plmTy6XKOyQ6vl@7EAM3Yd1e2eB8WQPBUj6yn1Zr29nhVH2y5ifC92QbLA1h7ry9vtVXZpgspIrZbcMVKD0b3Lfb64B1NK7pnHYS0xW5Q/WfTGqZh68d/uw62WNCAfgOOdfM2NExyADzqbrAGANx@AQ)

Comment: Ridiculously & unnecessarily complicated **and** for the same score as my boring, straightforward solution?! +1

Comment: @Shaggy Actually, they are similar enough. `s.slice(0,p-~c)` -> `d.slice(0,-~d[n])`, `q+1` -> `++n`, both recursive. Only difference is how to handle digits before the dot.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
≔⪪Ｓ.θＷ⊟ＥθΦκ‹ΣμＬκ⊞θ…⊟θＩ§ι⁰⪫θ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3LCoMwFET3fkVwdQNRLKXduJJCwVJB8AuCBhOMeZhr279PjbMYGDiHGSXfRst1jE0IajYwOK0QWuN2HHBTZgbKSF7mR3taZ1@ptCDQWwcdd@AZeSqNYoOFkbcIAYZ9hZWmYWaUsNAzpN@DTHRn9XTa/mAePCA02JpJ/EAxUiW0zvrjFuFllUlG@qZ1jEVVXq73Wyw@@g8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪Ｓ.θ
```

Split the input on `.`.

```
Ｗ⊟ＥθΦκ‹ΣμＬκ
```

Filter each part on those digits that are less than the string's length. Then take the last result. (This saves 1 byte over filtering on just the decimals.) Loop until that is empty.

```
⊞θ…⊟θＩ§ι⁰
```

Take the first filtered digit and truncate the decimals to that length.

```
⪫θ.
```

Join the parts back together and implicitly print.

Comment: Seems to give an incorrect result for the negative input-cases (although it is possible I don't know how to input negative values in Charcoal, I tried with a leading `-` or `_`, but both failed). Everything else works fine.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah, my final golf broke because it tried to cast `-` to integer. Fortunately I can use `Sum` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>84</s>, 78 bytes

Takes input as a pointer to a string buffer, outputs by modification. Note that providing a pointer to a buffer that is too small (`intPartLen + 1 + 9 > bufSize`) can cause `SEGFAULT`.

If assuming the size of the buffer to be sufficient is not allowed, +7 to the score.

```c
l,M;f(char*F){F=strchr(F,46);for(l=47,M=57;*++F&&++l<M;*F<M?M=*F:0);F[M-l]=0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7LasMwEDwnXyECCX5J6GVLquL2ppu/wM0hFTgxuGmw05QS8uvdykqhu7CzOzMM6/HBe4ChaGyX@ON@zFx6c/V0Gf1xTFwhq9R2H2My1FIVTV0qm@W522zyfNg2NnPb5qWpM/dEU@vaBg@7mto7vO/7U9KfLsgXaA5FWXZN0W25CFEoCj2qEbMBtsgHyPM0qIvoffvsWkbpzgZi/uP8nQSqQNe236Uz2c133M5jyOqS1XpC@Bmtp9fT6uEr0J/lvrwDMEVkZSTVnAOjRJacUS2BcUEkYC0VEVTxeFMwmqiqlCJ4gBLBqhIwJUwE1NwIReKMHI0NmJHHRoFrUmnJjQImiCjBGGL@68d3w/4wAf76BQ)

### Degolf

```c
l,M;f(char*F){
    F=strchr(F,46); // Find the pointer to the period.
    for(l=47,M=57;  // Initialize variables (48='0', 57='9')
            *++F&&++l<M;  // Check for null terminator, and that we're not
                          // going through too many decimals
            *F<M?M=*F:0); // Keep smaller of M and the char pointed to by F.
        F[M-l]=0; // Explained below.
}
```

At the end of the loop, `F` is a pointer to the `n`th decimal after the decimal point (`ptr`). `M` is the smallest digit observed as its ASCII value. `l` is `'0'+n-1` (or `47+n`). Thus:

```c
F[M-l] == *(F + M - l)
F[M-l] == *(ptr + n + M - '0' - n + 1)
F[M-l] == *(ptr + M - '0' + 1)
```

Which gives us a pointer to the first character to truncate; replacing this character with a `\0` results in the truncation of the remaining digits for most intents and purposes. This is also where the `SEGFAULT` happens; for example, if the input is `123.4`, the smallest digit is `4`, and the pointer will point to the character `*` in `123.4\0??*`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pl`, 48 bytes

```ruby
c=i=j=$_=~/,/;$_=$_[0,c.to_i-~j]while c=$_[i+=1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsJADITveQoP3szaZP8X2SeRUrAIbim2aEW89NFd1/VgApnMxzC3x@mVcx9THOK2i2uDzaHotjsS9vtl6pJYh/Z5SeN5039x2kVuc2aH2gZNXkpgQm0kk9fAUqEG4bVDRU5WTxA8Omu0KhkgVGwNCEJWRb0MymG9lVFdEIy/j0B6tF7L4IAVKlMKwn/e07yk6XrPYh4/)

Uses a decimal comma instead of a dot.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 92 bytes

several solutions, same length:

```
# any PHP:
for($n=$argn,$t=9;~$d=$n[$i+++$p=1+strpos($n,46)];$n=substr($n,0,$p+$t))$t<$d||$t=$d;echo$n;
for($t=9;$i<$t&&~$d=$n[$i+++$p=1+strpos($n=$argn,46)];)$t<$d||$t=$d;echo substr($n,0,$p+$t);
for($t=9;$i<$t&&~$d=$n[++$i+$p=strpos($n=$argn,46)];)$t<$d||$t=$d;echo substr($n,0,$p+$t+1);

# PHP 7:
for($t=9;~$d=($n=&$argn)[$i+++$p=1+strpos($n,46)];$n=substr($n,0,$p+$t))$t<$d||$t=$d;echo$n;
for($n=$argn;~$d=$n[$i+++$p=1+strpos($n,46)];$n=substr($n,0,$p+$t))($t??9)<$d||$t=$d;echo$n;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try (most of) them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1cdb748d133f6bcd5472dd2b186edd1c83a8e3dd).

Comment: I was like, wow, that's a long PHP answer. But then I saw the byte-count and realized they are four separated programs. ;) Btw, in what order does PHP execute `$i+++$p=1+strpos($n,46)`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `$i++`, then `$p=...`. `++$p=...` would throw a parse error.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 58 bytes

Input and output as a string, using a comma as the decimal separator.

```
s=>s.replace(/,.+/,g=d=>d[++n]?g(d.slice(0,-~d[n])):d,n=0)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bZJfb4IwFMXf/RSE@NCGK7b8Z0ndkw97W/bqSFopGg0rRHDR6PbVHaUQzbaS0HPOvbS/lO7Fp2jyw65uZ6qSxS2vVFOVhVtWW8RfVH1srXFcrbeiOZbt6JanusjbQhr3KprmXXGHz7h7KOpCtCgkGE827NawRaOzUuQFmoPrzGHLJFvIleOo7HmLpNuUu65GYPYtVyrD@EmCYgTfWrayaQxBlAYk8TwbbEogCD1KkkAbzwc9z5IgBp/E3pCRbk4TiKMw8LvezhHwaRTqVgLU71XipX4M/XvISf9oQ8Fo/amXQJQEXqq7qA9@2C@X3ofp6Tays8nhDmyDPhkDPGrDaxngh1BnA/CQdsC96sGMGoF/5b2hMGrLAI@L/wXWFQNsW9lk8vjHW/dD1Aid4IzZgk8vpy/u1kIulUQ0wA6/WtOLYBt0wv8U1uywOmd/CtxBgrE1xu6@2ine3RF8@wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>78</s> 68 bytes

*-10 bytes from @tsh*

```javascript
a=>eval('for([x,y]=a.split`.`,i=0;c=y[i++];y=y.slice(0,c));x+`.`+y')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLdjoIwEIWv3acg3ghBxumPUELqK@wDGBMJCxs2RAygkadnKeJqllHbhNCefqeHGX7ic1wnVX5svEP5lXaZ7mK9Sc9xYS@ysrK3l2W70zHUxyJv9rBf5hqjRLfb3HV3UatbqIs8SW1cJo4TXdz@iNsunC4pD3VZpFCU33Zmz1kA0g8lKs7njuVa89lqZX2ejqfG0htrVHvFjNnHfxhBrjlDJSnWiCNJoFwASZl9RLTssrounJsHbeQpGYDAgIpvtMFoOHQ3ItMgneYvyJscoYLAX0vRl4MwGtVnhUQQzF8TXC88Xjv9egQmSNIoD@iEVDwUAQxPgr6pzwIbdxzmm6unJIMrSJXJY9d2sXu1JwZcga8kD6nYg/aizQIEVathf/zlzOubViOE90E27UHtfgE)

Comment: [A quick saving](https://tio.run/##bcvRDoIgAIXha3sKxo0wSNFR2Ry@Qg/g3GCGRWPiAs23p9y6ap2rs337H2pRvn@aKexHd9VxEFGJRi/KonQVKvOTNUFSSY1g9eturEYoiLUtOtyaDm9HhMxb02vEaGgNIR2uVyJlimPvRu@szqy7oQHB4kT58cxZVZYQAwJgkufgMk9zAKIBX/3ItmT3GzPKD2XBKv6v3RDi@AY) using comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZLdjoIwEIWv3acg3ghBxumPUELqK@wDGBMJCxs2RAygkadnKeJqllHbhNCefqeHGX7ic1wnVX5svEP5lXaZ7mK9Sc9xYS@ysrK3l2W70zHUxyJv9rBf5hqjRLfb3HV3UatbqIs8SW1cJo4TXdz@iNsunC4pD3VZpFCU33Zmz1kA0g8lKs7njuVa89lqZX2ejqfG0htrVHvFjNnHfxhBrjlDJSnWiCNJoFwASZl9RLTssrounJsHbeQpGYDAgIpvtMFoOHQ3ItMgneYvyJscoYLAX0vRl4MwGtVnhUQQzF8TXC88Xjv9egQmSNIoD@iEVDwUAQxPgr6pzwIbdxzmm6unJIMrSJXJY9d2sXu1JwZcga8kD6nYg/aizQIEVathf/zlzOubViOE90E27UHtfgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg) `-p`, <s>57</s> 41 bytes

```perl6
$!=m/\./.to;.=substr(0,$!+$/)while m:c/./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RUzLCsJAELvPV1joQdGdndnZp9I/8aQULLS2tBX/3rWsBxNIMkPI1M69z7mumkFfUeM6XrBZXrdlnfd0qqtjrQ/vR9e3u@F816hz5oDWJ0vRGGBC6wxTtMBG0IKKNqBQMOUmSBGDd1a2DhAKeweKkGXzaJIELFp@VAiK8ZcITEQfrUkBWFDcNpD@@IzT2o3PJavpCw)

#### Explanation

```perl6
$!=m/\./.to;       # Store position of decimal point in $!
.=substr(0,$!+$/)  # Truncate string to length $!+$/
while m:c/./       # while there's a match for the next digit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

```python
g,h=input().split(".")
for i in h:h=h[:int(i)]if i in h else h
print(g+"."+h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P10nwzYzr6C0RENTr7ggJ7NEQ0lPSZMrLb9IIVMhM08hwyrDNiPaKjOvRCNTMzYzDSqqkJpTnKqQwVVQBJJJ1wZq0s7Q/P8fAA)

Somehow, despite slicing past the end of a string and modifying while iterating on that same string, the interpreter doesn't complain.

This answer has a similar structure to the other Python one, but uses a different method to find where to truncate and works in newer versions of Python.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 115 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text
$s#[i,d:_]=split['.']s
=i++['.':iter 9(\p=hd([take n\\n<-map digitToInt p|n<length p]++[id])p)d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBba4MwFH6uvyKwgco0xMR6Ge3b9lDYYNC@aRiuZm2YRqnpLrDfPhet2qxMwZzv4nfOybZgmWjLKj8WDJQZFy0v6@ogwVrm9@Ld2bBPaVw3Vwl38ttnumzqgsvEhCZtjCW/uenKWy7ZAcRWWi/3uZXI7I0BkaZi4ZZZDXK@43JTrYQE9bdYFEzs5B7UVP3Lc2rXdk7btcxUyyVIePPIyheVZl0DLuqjtEF1lOpsQJoCq6eckbLBwgWSNbKhxseeHZgx61EXZMxmVmJ6IfSD2EcRxiZ1QDIxJqW2M3gQ9OfYQ5E/WjpCN2ACJ62rEUIKTsJkdCM/hASFY68O98ZeuEhE58QpTLPEEQyDuU/UYINxYDQPgsQL5oOsgD4Kgh6ZtA5pYoRjEsL@OxhG5iIB9e//Ia4HT/I4n@uddvX0NXAEg8jH8diox/pNEEjGKft6uNkTrW0an59pYY3RG6o7O3cj@E/MPPADPAV0qJOVStuf7WuR7ZrWXT20d18iK/n2BJ6KTL5Wh/IX)

Defines the function `$ :: [Char] -> [Char]`. Link includes test suite.